# What is "Aware" ? When should I include in my Class name?

Tags: java, spring, naming-conventions

Sometimes, I find some class names including **Aware** such as `ApplicationContextAware` and `MessageSourceAware` (spring). Does this **Aware** have any special meanings or is it a famous rule?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Those are not classes, are interfaces. The name is just a convention on Spring meaning that some special framework object is going to be injected to that class if it is managed by the framework.

Directly from the docs of [ApplicationContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html):

> Interface to be implemented by any object that wishes to be notified of the ApplicationContext that it runs in.

In this case, the bean that implements this interface will get a reference to the ApplicationContext managing the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm getting understand. For example, if you find an interface named "EmploymentEntityAwareService", you would think the service implemented by any object have "Employment" entity as a field, right?

Comment: @yusaku Possibly, it's not really a hard rule. Aware is mostly a Spring convention, I wouldn't recommend using it in your own classnames unless you have a really good reason to. What Spring is basically saying with it's use of "Aware" is "this class is now aware that it's being managed by Spring". Typically you want to avoid using these interfaces directly to keep your code from being dependent on the Spring Framework. They're provided to handle the isolated cases where a class must interact directly with the Spring container.

Comment: @Jberg Thanks! All right, I'll be careful to use it if I need.

Answer (score 6):

Appending adjectives like "aware" to the end is a naming scheme often used for Java interfaces. This can then be implemented by classes, and the resulting is code which is more fluent to read for human beings, like

```
class Broker implements ApplicationContextAware { /* ... */ }
```

where it's quite easy to see that this class is a broker for something, and it knows how to deal with application contexts. Besides that, the "Aware" suffix has no special meaning from the Java (compiler) perspective.

Comment: I'm currently not *aware* of some, maybe I'd have been better of saying "adjectives" are for interfaces rather than elaborating about the suffix convention used in Spring. Hm.

Comment: @Michael, I have some *aware*  interfaces (like TransactionAware) and I have never used spring but I'd not call it 'often' used.

Answer (score 2):

The interfaces you cite seem to be a Spring-specific convention for allowing objects to interact with the dependency injection container that created them. By implementing the interface, a class signals that it wants certain information from the container and at the same time provides a method through which to pass that information.

I'd see it simply as an attempt to find a generic name for an interface that offers such functionality, not necessarily a strong convention with a specific technical meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting clear. If you have more time, could I have any comments on my another question which is written in @mdrg's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of aware interfaces:

If I want the reference of objects of spring classes like `XmlBeanFactory`,`ApplicationContext`... In 2 or more classes, then there are 3 possible ways are there.

1. creating 2 `BeanFactories` in two classes.
2. creating at one class and sharing to all required classes .

In the 1st case ,we are unnecessarely creating 2 BeanFactories.
In the 2nd case, classes are tightly coupled with each other.

3. If our class  implements `BeanFactoryAware` interface and overrides the contractual method called `public BeanFactory setBeanFactory(BeanFactory factory)` then `IOC container` see that special interface  and calls `setBeanFactory` method by setting `BeanFactory` reference to that.

In 3. case above two problems are not there.